# UWP crashes when entering in a User Name and password

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

this is my first post. I will try to get all of the relevant info. I am developing a UWP for my BS Capstone class. I have a mainpage that gives the user the choice to enter in a user name and password and log in, or enter a user name and password and register so they will be able to log in. I have some exceptions in there in the event that a user is not registered, a dialog will inform them they need to register. 
The problem is when I enter in a user name and password that I know is not registered, the app crashes. 
I am using VS 2015 and an Azure SQL database. The only clue i have to whats wrong is the output shows the following message.
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Also, I have the connection string in the App.Xaml.cs tab as

```
 public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new 
 MobileServiceClient("http://tale-server1.database.windows.net");
```

Finally, when trying to register a new user, the Catch exception fires of:

```
catch (Exception em)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("An Error Occured: " + 
em.Message);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

My Mainpage code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SQLite;
using SQLite.Net;
using SQLite.Net.Async;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;
using SQLitePCL;


// The Blank Page item template is documented at 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace TALE_Capstone
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a 
Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int IsAuth { get; set; }

    //[DataTable("User_Cred")]
    public class User_Cred
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }

    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<User_Cred> todoGetTable = 
App.MobileService.GetSyncTable<User_Cred>();



    private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
    {
        if (!App.MobileService.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
        {
            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("Tale-DB");
            store.DefineTable<User_Cred>();
            await App.MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
        }
        await SyncAsync();
    }

    private async Task SyncAsync()
    {
        await App.MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
        await todoGetTable.PullAsync("User_Cred", 
todoGetTable.CreateQuery());
    }



    async public void submitAuthBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await InitLocalStoreAsync();

        GetAuthentication();

    }

    async public void GetAuthentication()
    {
        try
        {

            //IMobileServiceTable<User_Cred> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<User_Cred>();

            List<User_Cred> items = await todoGetTable
                .Where(User_Cred => User_Cred.userName == UserNameEnter.Text) 
                .ToListAsync();

            IsAuth = items.Count();

            // Return a List UI control value back to the form

            foreach (var value in items)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog("Welcome Back  " + value.userName);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }


            if (IsAuth > 0)
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog("You are Authenticated");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();

            }
            else
            {
                var dialog = new MessageDialog(" Account Does Not Exist, please Register to get Started.");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception em)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("An Error Occured: " + em.Message);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    async private void submitAuthBtn_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            User_Cred itemReg = new User_Cred
            {
                userName = UserNameEnter.Text,
                Password = PWEnter.Text
            };
            await App.MobileService.GetTable<User_Cred>().InsertAsync(itemReg);
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("Thank you for Registering! Lets begin");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception em)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("An Error Occured: " + em.Message);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }



}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Conrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you are connecting your UWP app with the Azure Mobile App backend and Azure SQL database for storing data. AFAIK, the initialization of `MobileServiceClient` would look like as follows:

```
MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("https://{your-appname}.azurewebsites.net");
```

I would recommend you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started) and download the [sample client project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started#download-and-run-the-client-project) to check this issue. Also, you could leverage [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and collect the network traces when you connect your uwp app with azure mobile app to get the detailed error message, then you could narrow this issue or you could update your question with the detailed error for us to locate this issue.

Comment: I actually figured out that I was missing a reference. Thank you for the effort though :)